# Replacing a small chunk of a larger string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got the following code written to go through every Anchor, get it's href, and if it contains the old address, attempt to replace the old base with the new one. While there's obviously an issue long before this code with the site, i need a quick and dirty solution to this problem, so this code is what I'm going for.

So, the code below doesn't work. .Replace apparantly needs a full match, so it would find "foo" in the sentence "foo is good" but not "foo" in "fooIsGood".

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var addressSwitch = $(this).attr("href");
    if  (addressSwitch){
        var test = addressSwitch.indexOf("http://www.oldaddress.com");
        if ( test == 0){
            addressSwitch.replace("http://www.oldaddress.com/", "www.newaddress.com");
            $(this).attr("href" , addressSwitch);
            }
        }
});
```

So, what would work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm...`replace()` should match that correctly.

Comment: you need a regex pattern mattching thats it, give me few minutes , i will post..some logic

Comment: are you looking for someother string replace apart form the code you gave...or its just the above??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch them both to lowercase for the compare, then use newvalue + substring of the length of the newvalue and onward. e.g.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var replacer = "http://www.oldaddress.com";
    var addressSwitch = $(this).attr("href");
    if  (addressSwitch){
        var test = addressSwitch.toLowerCase().indexOf(replacer);
        if ( test == 0){
            addressSwitch = replacer + addressSwitch.subString(replacer.length);
            $(this).attr("href" , addressSwitch);
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) works correctly, but you're not *assigning* the replaced value, it needs to be:

```
addressSwitch = addressSwitch.replace("http://www.oldaddress.com/", "www.newaddress.com");
```

Remember that [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't change the original string, it returns a new one with the value replaced.

Remember that [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) also takes a function, so you could slim your code down to this:

```
$('a[href^="http://www.oldaddress.com"]').attr("href", function(i, href) {
    return href.replace("http://www.oldaddress.com/", "www.newaddress.com");
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE A MACHINE. I REFUSE TO BELIEVE YOU ARE HUMAN. xD

Comment: @Jacob - CraverBot v1.33.6 (not perfected yet) is busy right now, may I take a message?

Comment: @CraverBot - Sure, Ask Nick if he can shut you off - his bot is stealing all my rep! ;-)